# Server checkbox not working properly

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I am trying to make an arduino alarm clock to which you can send alarm clock times over the web.
This is the HTML code

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="alarm1" id="alarm1">1</button>
```

It's sending the HTTP correctly but the rest of the code insists that the alarms are always on.

```
      if (_server.arg("alarm1") = "on") {
      alarm1 = true;
      Serial.println("Alarm 1 is set");
  }
  else {
      alarm1 = false;
      Serial.println("Alarm 1 is inactive");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alarm is always on because you are setting it to be always on.  You code should say:

```
 if (_server.arg("alarm1") == "on") {
```

Comment: To clarify, one equal sign is used to assign a value to a variable, two equal signs is used to determine if one value equals another.